# what is the meaning of the two sentences

Tags: meaning, tense, participles

> Flowers are planted in the garden. [*planted*: past participle, past tense of *plant*]

> Flowers are planting in the garden. [*planting*: present participle of *plant*]

What is the meaning of the above two sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Flowers are planted in the garden* means that *Flowers* are being planted in the garden. *Flowers are planting in the garden* means that the *Flowers* are doing some planting of their own in the garden, which is quite unusual.

Comment: what about this one "we are planting Flowers in my garden" and "Flowers are planted in my garden". what is the meaning of above two sentences.

Comment: They both make sense. "We are planting flowers in my garden" has the same meaning as "Flowers are _being_ planted in my garden _by us_"

Comment: @Radu: You can leave off the _by us_ in that sentence; I think most native speakers would omit that. Moreover, I think it would be rare to hear someone word it that way (although you're right about the meaning). I think the second structure would be more likely to be heard if someone else was doing the planting, e.g.: _The landscaper is coming tomorrow; flowers are being planted in the garden._

Comment: @J.R. I know, that's why I emphasized it. I imagined that this is a question from a non-native speaker so I added it just to be crystal clear